# like bewteen two tables my sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables. One is the `users` table

```
id - name - skills
```

and the other is the `jobs` table

```
job_id - job-title - job_description
```

I tried this query, so when selecting any word in `skills` in first table get `job title`s. Like this:

```
   SELECT *FROM users INNER JOIN jobs ON users.site_keywords || '%' + jobs.job_description + '%'"
```

But it didn't work.

Any help  for that?
Thank you

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: your sql query is not proper. Could you post the complete query and actual attribute names in the tables that you wish to join?

Comment: SELECT users.name,users.site_keywords ,jobs.job_title,jobs.job_description from users,jobs

Comment: i want to select between site keyword and job_title

Comment: i try this now it work but it git first word only in site_keywords  ((SELECT users.site_keywords,jobs.job_title FROM users ,jobs  WHERE users.site_keywords like jobs.job_title))

Comment: which db you are using ?? ..and what  mean the column  site_keywords in your query  .. you don't mention in your schema

Comment: I tried to improve the formatting and wording to make it better understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For string macthing you should use LIKE 
and for string concatenation use agnostic   CONCAT

```
"SELECT * 
 FROM users 
 INNER JOIN jobs ON users.site_keywords  LIKE  concat('%' ,jobs.job_title , '%') "
```

Comment: thank you a lot it work like this ((SELECT users.site_keywords,jobs.job_title FROM users INNER JOIN jobs ON users.site_keywords LIKE concat('%' ,jobs.job_title , '%')....thank you have a nice day ^_^